# setTimeout inside a Ajax in a foreach

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to call a function after 1 second, but this function is called in a ajax inside a foreach.

Code:

```
let index = 1;
portais.forEach(portal => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                index++;
                text(index, total); // I want to call this function, after 1 second
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

but only call at first and last time.

I already tried put this function inside a async function and using a promise to solve but still doens't worked.
Here is the other code that I tried:

```
let index = 1;
const delay = (amount = number) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, amount);
    });
}

async function forPortais(){
    for(index; index<=total; index++){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: `/exportacao/${portais[index].arquivo}.php`,
            async: false,
            success: async function (data) {
                if(index>total){
                    text(index, total);
                    await delay(1000);

            }
        });
    }
}
forPortais();
```

- How can I call this function `text()` after 1 second?

The result expected is that this function being called 7 times, with a timeout of 1 second.

Comment: so `setTimeout(()=>text(index, total), 1000)`

Comment: If you want a constant timeout of 1 second you could just use `x = setInterval(text, 1000)` from outside the ajax part and after the 7th time call `clearInterval(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve this question creating an async foreach, and a async delay too.

The code:

```
const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

    const asyncForEach = async function(array, callback) {
        for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            await callback(array[index], index, array)
        }
    }

    const start = async () => {
        await asyncForEach(portais, async (portal) => {
            await waitFor(100);
            text(index, total);
            index++;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                async: false,
            });
        })
    }
    start();
```

Answer (score -1):

with this function you can do what you want, but will be very expensive for your browser

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while(true){
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
        }
    }
}

let index = 1;
portais.forEach(portal => {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            index++;
            sleep(1000);
            text(index, total);
        }
    });
});
```